# Chance of UDP failure on the same machine?

Tags: c#, udp

I was wondering if anyone could give me an idea of what the chances are, maybe in percentage, of the failure of a UDP datagram being lost/corrupted when sent from server to server application on the same machine?

It would be in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Datagrams will get lost if they are not processed as quickly as they are generated, because you fill the receive buffer. Datagrams larger than the MTU may also be dropped.

Comment: Any idea on the chances of this happening on the same server machine?

Comment: For these scenarios, 100% even when the applications are on the same host

Comment: Thank you, sir. I'll stick with tcp, eh?

Comment: If you want reliable datagrams you can use Windows named pipes or UNIX domain sockets